# Short Shuffle Textbox1 equal with Textbox2

Tags: vb.net

[image: Image Textbox.Text and Textbox2.Text]

If I change the positions in Textbox1.text (Shuffle Text Random) how do they change automatically in Textbox2.Text? I mean any changes I make in Textbox1, to be done in the 2nd textbox. If you change the position of line 2 in the first Textbox, and put the first position. then in the second textbox they want the same change. Everywhere it refers to Textbox1 add another line the same but referring to Textbox2.

Comment: In the code which does the shuffling, everywhere it refers to Textbox1 add another line the same but referring to Textbox2.

Comment: not realy. I just want to change the lines (positions), that is, what changes they make in Textbox1, to be done in the 2nd.

Comment: Yes. that's correct.

Comment: You can simply use a `List(Of Class)`, where the class has two `String` properties, one for Textbox1 and the other for TextBox2. When you shuffle/reorder the List, the pairs are still pairs, in a different presentation order. You could also use a different control for the presentation of the synched lines (a DataGridView, for example).